# Calling a function returned by a constructor in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Given the following code, e.g. an Angular filter:

```
class ToLowerFilter
{
    constructor()
    {
        return (value: string) => value.toLowerCase();
    }
}
myAngularApp.filter("toLower", ToLowerFilter);
```

If I wanted to use this in another context, normally you could inject the `$filter` reference and do something like:

```
var filteredValue = $filter('toLower')(myValueToBeLowered);
```

However the TypeScript compiler complains about this, saying that `$filter(...)` does not return an invokable type.

If I wanted to use the `ToLowerFilter` class directly, how would I do that with TypeScript? None of these methods work: (TypeScript either generates a transpile error, or it's not the correct JavaScript syntax)

```
// define $filter: ng.IFilterService
var filteredValue = $filter('toLower')(value);    

var filter = new ToLowerFilter();
var filteredValue = filter(value);

var filteredValue = new ToLowerFilter(value);

var filteredValue = new ToLowerFilter()(value);
```

Comment: Why not make ToLowerFilter a function that returns a function?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (though maybe not the best) is to cast the `$filter` to a function type first, then invoke it:

```
var filterFunction = $filter('toLowerFilter') as (value: string) => string;
var filteredValue = filterFunction(myValue);
```

It's not pretty, and it doesn't use the TypeScript class, but at least it doesn't produce an error.

I'd love to hear other possible ways of doing this.